# Why is vsprintf() bit-shifting an 8-bit number?

Tags: c, printf, 8-bit

I'm using the Keil Cx51 compiler on an 8-bit EFM8 MCU.

If I have a function, `foo()`, like this:

```
xdata char buf[32];

void foo(char *msg, ...) 
{
    va_list args;
    va_start (args, msg);
    vsprintf(buf, msg, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
foo("My number is %d", 1);
```

`buf` will contain: "My number is **256**".

If I change the call to:

```
foo("My number is %d", (uint16_t)1);
```

Then `buf` will contain "My number is **1**", as expected.

Why is `vsprintf()` bit-shifting the number 1 (0x0001) left by 8 bits to 256 (0x0100) without a cast? Is this an endianness issue?

Comment: Looks more like an integer promotion issue.  Keil does [have a web page](http://www.keil.com/support/docs/1754.htm) about it.

Comment: Thanks for that link. I just disabled integer promotion as per the instructions and retested - the issue still remains. I am using Cx51 v9.53.

Comment: That's backwards, you want it enabled.  Do consider posting the assembly code.

Comment: It's enabled by default. Please see attached assembly for the case where it's enabled.

Comment: Q: What is the data type of the expression, `1` in Keil C?  And, what data type does `%d` expect?  In the C programming language, the answer to both questions is `int`; but Keil C is not C. It's been too long since I wrote code for an 8052, but if I had to guess, I'd guess that the data type of `1` might be `char`.

Comment: @jameslarge If `%d` expects an `int`, and I pass it a `char` of `1`, wouldn't it still be `1` as an `int`? This is why I thought it might be an endianness issue, as I could see that being a problem if I passed it a `char`, it turned it into a 16-bit `int` and `vsprintf()` read it in the 'other' endianness?.

Comment: It's been ten years since the last time I used Keil C.  I can't answer those questions.  I can only suggest that _you_ ask them.  I would not assume that Keil C obeys any particular rule that standard C obeys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known problem that the data types of arguments in a functions having a "`...`" argument list matter because the compiler is normally not able to automatically adjust the data types.

*Maybe* some compilers will automatically detect the format specifiers in `printf` and adjust the data types in the arguments accordingly. GNU C for example will parse the string and print a warning message that the data types do not match but it does *not* adjust the data types.

If you don't use the correct data type you'll definitely get bad results.

Obviously `%d` means 16 bit for your compiler but `1` is some other data type (e.g. 8 bit).

Maybe with your compiler an argument list of the following form:

```
(uint8)a, (uint16)b, (uint8)c, (uint8)d
```

May be stored in the memory like this:

```
a, high_byte_of(b), low_byte_of(b), c, d
```

If the function expects `c` to be a 16-bit value the function will interpret the `c` in the memory as the high 8 bits of `c` and it will interpret `d` in the argument list as low 8 bits of `d`...

So in your case if you do the following:

```
foo("%d, %d", 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

The memory would look like this:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, ...
```

... and `vsprintf` will interpret this as 0x102 and 0x304, not as 1 and 2.

Of course in the RAM the `4` is followed by some other bytes which are not related to this part of the program so the RAM content maybe looks like this:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 19, 32, 54, 21, 32, ...
```

In your case the first byte in the RAM would be a `1` followed by some "random" data (data not related to the function call).

Obviously the first byte after the `1` is a `0` so the `vsprintf` function interprets this as 0x0100.

If you use `(uint16)1` as arguments the byte `0` followed by `1` will be written to the RAM so `vsprintf` interprets this as 0x0001.

Comment: Very interesting indeed, thanks for the explanation.